# Binary search through an array of even numbers increasing and odd numbers decreasing?

Tags: java, search, binary-search

I know my code is a mess and I'm sorry for that, I tried to write it as fast as possible and than to arrange the statements.

it works for most cases but not for {19,17,2,15,6,13,12,7,16,3,22}.

as you can see it should be simple, the array can be sorted in any way, but the even numbers always increase from the beginning to the end, and the odd numbers decrease.

what I tried to do was a regular binary search with some conditions to check if we look at an even or odd number and than adjust accordingly.

Edit: I forgot to mention it's a question I'm trying to solve, they said specifically **search** the array in the most efficient way.

```
public static int find(int[] arr,int n)
{
    final boolean EVEN;

    if (n%2==0)
     EVEN = true;
    else
     EVEN = false;

    int min = 0, max = arr.length-1;
    int m = 0;
    do
    {
        m = (min+max)/2;

        if (n == arr[m])
         break;

        if (arr[m]%2==0)
        {
            if (EVEN)
            {
                if (n>arr[m])
                 min = m+1;
                else
                 max = m-1;

            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    m--;
                }
                while(arr[m]%2==0);

                if (arr[m]==n)
                 break;

                if (n>arr[m])
                 max = m-1;
                else
                 min = m+1;                

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!EVEN)
            {
                if (n>arr[m])
                 max = m-1;
                else
                 min = m+1;                    
            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    m++;
                }
                while(arr[m]%2!=0);                   

                if (arr[m]==n)
                 break;

                if (n>arr[m])
                 min = m+1;
                else
                 max = m-1;    


            }
        }
    }while(min<max);

    if (arr[m]==n)
     return m;
    else
     return -1;        
}
```

Comment: And your question is? Also, why not sort the array and use a binary search?

Comment: it's not a binary search if you are not sorting all the numbers

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it's a question... it says find the number in this array in the most efficient way... sorting will be at least (nlogn) and I prefer to stay at the (logn) range

Comment: Uh, binary search doesn't work on non sorted arrays!

Comment: guys, it is a sorted array! (kinda) odd numbers are sorted and even numbers are sorted!

Comment: Well, your "kinda" is the problem here

Comment: so binary search is wrong here? what is the most time complexity wise best idea to search this array without sorting it?

Comment: @Elliot, it's not smart, at all. if I sort the array i'm already at O(nlogn), than binary search it at O(logn), the method will run at O(nlogn). I can just search it regularly and get better results at O(n). I still think binary search is required in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
while(min<=max);
```

You might be missing the cases where min and max coincide.

**Update**:

Yup! I checked it. I ran your program against

```
int[] array = {19,17,2,15,6,13,12,7,16,3,22};
```

for all values and it works as expected if you make that correction.